# How to return to the original directory after invoking change directory in DOS batch?

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file, `batch.bat`, that accepts 2 mandatory arguments:

- `%1` represents a path relative to the current directory.
- `%2` represents a filaname.

Assume the current directory is `father\me\`.

User can use this batch as follows:

- `batch child/grandchild log`
- `batch ../brother log`

The job description of `batch.bat` is as follows.

1. Moves to `%1` directory,
2. Iterates all `*.tex` file in the `%1` directory.
3. Save the result in the directory before moving.

The following is the incomplete code:

```
rem batch.bat takes 2 arguments.
cd %1
dir /b *.tex > <original directory>\%2.txt
```

How to return to the original directory after invoking change directory in DOS batch?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you want to RETURN to original directory, do the first change with `PUSHD` and return with `POPD`. That is, moves to %1 directory must be achieved with

```
PUSHD %1
```

instead of CD %1, and the return is achieved with

```
POPD
```

instead of CD where?

If you want to ACCESS the original directory after changed it, store it in a variable this way:

```
SET ORIGINAL=%CD%
```

and use %ORIGINAL% later, for example:

```
dir /b *.tex > %original%\%2.txt
```

Comment: +1: additionally PUSHD is used to CD into network-attached drives, as CD will not allow you to.

Comment: Where was that comment a year ago when I was using batch, and having to work around networked drives? +100 if I could

Answer (score 17):

Definitely PUSHD / POPD is the preferred way to do this. But there is a (undocumented?) feature of SETLOCAL / ENDLOCAL that accomplishes the same thing (in addition to everything else SETLOCAL does).

If you change directory after a SETLOCAL, then you will return to the original directory upon ENDLOCAL.

```
cd OriginalLocation
setlocal
cd NewLocation
endlocal
rem we are back to OriginalLocation
```

One other thing with SETLOCAL that *is* documented - Any SETLOCAL within a called batch or :label routine will be terminated with an implicit ENDLOCAL upon exiting the batch or routine. The implicit ENDLOCAL will return to the original folder just as an explicit ENDLOCAL.

```
cd OriginalLocation
call :ChangeLocation
rem - We are back to OriginalLocation because :ChangeLocation did CD after a SETLOCAL
rem - and there is an implicit ENDLOCAL upon return
exit /b

:ChangeLocation
setlocal
cd NewLocation
exit /b
```

I wouldn't recommend using SETLOCAL/ENDLOCAL instead of PUSHD/POPD. But it is a behavior you should be aware of.

***Response to johnny's comment***

It can get confusing when PUSHD/POPD and SETLOCAL/ENDLOCAL are combined. The ENDLOCAL does ***not*** clear the PUSHD stack, as evidenced by the following:

```
setlocal
cd test
@cd
pushd new
@cd
endlocal
@cd
popd
@cd
```

--OUTPUT--

```
D:\test>setlocal

D:\test>cd test
D:\test\test

D:\test\test>pushd new
D:\test\test\new

D:\test\test\new>endlocal
D:\test

D:\test>popd
D:\test\test
```

Comment: @johnny - Not true (at least not true on Win 7 where I tested). The pushd stack is preserved. See my updated answer.

Comment: my bad; I swear I'd tested that over and over before posting (since it did seem strange), but I deleted my test scripts when I was done with them and now can't duplicate what I _thought_ I was seeing... unmatched pushd/popd's within scripts or subroutines can still be an issue, though...

Answer (score 5):

```
set ORIGINAL_DIR=%CD% 

REM #YOUR BATCH LOGIC HERE

chdir /d %ORIGINAL_DIR%
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always set %cd% to a variable before changing directories:

```
set current="%cd%"
cd "C:\Some\Other\Folder"
cd "%current%"
```

In most cases, creating a variable with the directory is used in Batch Scripts. If the script is semi-lengthy, I will define my variables in the beginning of the script that includes important paths, files, subs, and/or long commands.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Variables
::Programs
SET save_attachments=C:\Program Files\APED\Program\save_attachments.vbs
SET sendemail=C:\Program Files\APED\Program\sendkeys.vbs
SET tb=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe
SET fox=C:\Program Files\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe
SET spool=C:\WINDOWS\system32\PRNJOBS.vbs

::Directories
SET new=C:\Program Files\APED\New
SET printing=C:\Program Files\APED\Printing
SET finish=C:\Program Files\APED\Finish
SET messages=C:\Program Files\APED\Script_Messages
SET nonpdf=C:\Program Files\APED\NonPDFfiles
SET errorfiles=C:\Program Files\APED\Error Files

::Important Files
SET printlog=C:\Program Files\APED\Script_Messages\PrintLOG.txt
SET printemail=C:\Program Files\APED\Script_Messages\EmailPrintLOG.txt
SET errorlog=C:\Program Files\APED\Script_Messages\ErrorLOG.txt
SET erroremail=C:\Program Files\APED\Script_Messages\EmailErrorLOG.txt
SET movefiles=C:\Program Files\APED\Script_Messages\MoveFiles.txt
```

However, PUSHD and POPD are great solutions if it is short and sweet imo.